# Как локализовать русскую дату?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Я использую gem russian. следующий код работает:

```
<div class="col-sm-3"><%= Russian::strftime(Time.now) %></div>
```

Но мне нужно чтобы работал следующий код:

```
<% @all_diary.each do |diary| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to user_path(diary.id) do %>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><%= diary.name %></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><%= diary.created_at.to_time.strftime('%e %b %Y') %></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><%= diary.updated_at.to_time.strftime('%e %b %Y') %></div>
      <% end %>  
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Проблема в том, что дата выводится не локализованная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strftime` наплевать на текущую локаль. В принципе. Чтобы локализовать даты, установите локаль в конфиге (или где вам угодно), а затем форматируйте даты следующим образом:

```
I18n.l(diary.created_at.to_time, :format => '%e %b %Y')
```

Гем Russian магически ваш код тоже не изменит. Чтобы форматировать даты с его помощью, пишите явно:

```
Russian::strftime(diary.created_at.to_time)
```

См. [Stop Using strftime](http://astrails.com/blog/2013/8/6/stop-using-strftime).